# Is there a way to repeat a value until other is found in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

I want to know if is possible to repeat the value of the current row until I found another one and then repeat that

I have tried some function with CASE WHEN or OPERATION with ROW_NUMBER but I cant do much

WHEN DATE=201903 always is going to be the value of act_CODE and that's the first value is going to put in the result

[image: this is what I get]

[image: this is the result I want]

Comment: I don't fully understand the logic.  What if there is a `NULL` values between 15 and 21?  Which does it get?

Comment: it takes the value 21 until 15 is found then all rows from there going to have 15

Comment: I *think* this is a gaps and islands question? I think the data we have is the data the OP received from a query we don't have, and the results they are after. We really need sample data and expected results for that data.

Comment: Can you put your test query to check what you have try so for.